# Найти коэффициент полинома C#

Tags: c#

Я пишу программу, способную решать уравнения / системы с помощью [этой библиотеки](https://symbolics.mathdotnet.com).

Мне нужен способ, с помощью которого можно легко вычислить коэффициент полинома, что-то вроде:

```
string input = "(x - 5)(x + 2) = 0"
int degree = DeterminePolynomialDegree(input) //тут degree == 2
```

Comment: Вам нужно написать систему символьной математики, наподобие Wolfram Alpha. Пару лет работы и учёная степень по алгебре — и дело в шляпе!

Comment: @VladD Я знаю, что самому этого не написать, но наверняка же есть библиотеки или методы в моей библиотеке, способные сделать то, что я хочу

Comment: Тьфу, не обратил внимание на библиотеку. Да, там должна быть функциональность по теме: https://symbolics.mathdotnet.com/

Comment: @VladD Тем более, учитывая то, что это полином: если упростить раздельно обе стороны уравнения, а потом вычесть одну из другой, тогда получим уравнение формы anx^n + a(n-1)x^(n-1) + a0 = 0, сплитнем эту строку и наш результат будет длина получившегося массива - 1. Без степени по алгебре)

Comment: Не, тут не так просто. Вам придётся для начала написать парсер выражений само по себе задача не на один день. Ну и если у вас получится выражение `x^100 + 1`, как собираетесь сплитнуть? Низкоуровневыми функциями типа Split вы ничего не добьётесь.

Comment: @VladD, парсер есть в той библиотеке как раз: [Math.NET Symbolics with F# and F# Interactive](https://symbolics.mathdotnet.com/)

Comment: @Grundy: Но он не парсит человеческую нотацию, хочет звёздочку для умножения. :-\

Comment: @VladD, подозреваю, что входную строку можно изменять в соответствии с грамматикой

Comment: @Grundy: Не распарсив её перед этим вручную? :-D

Comment: @VladD, я имел ввиду можно так: `string input = "(x - 5)*(x + 2)"`, ну либо тупой заменой `)(`, на `)*(`

Comment: @Grundy: Чёта я сомневаюсь, что такая замена всегда валидна.

Comment: @Grundy: Например, `2 sin x cos x` — где вставлять умножение и скобки?

Comment: @VladD, Так я только про скобки и говорил :-)

Comment: Если у вас возникнут какие-либо вопросы связанные с этой библиотекой или возможно предложения по поводу функционала который вы хотели бы видеть - можете пинговать меня в [чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f) , попробую помочь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня получилось вот так:

```
using MathNet.Symbolics;
using Expr = MathNet.Symbolics.Expression;
```

```
var expr = Infix.ParseOrThrow("(x - 5)*(x + 2)"); // без звёздочки не парсит :(
var expanded = Algebraic.Expand(expr);
var xsym = Expr.Symbol("x");
if (SingleVariablePolynomial.IsPolynomial(xsym, expanded))
{
    var degreeExpr = SingleVariablePolynomial.Degree(xsym, expanded);
    var degree = Evaluate.Evaluate(null, degreeExpr).RealValue;
    Console.WriteLine($"Degree: {degree}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a polynomial in x");
}
```

---

С двумя переменными не сложнее:

```
var expr = Infix.ParseOrThrow("(x - 5)*(x + 2) + x * y");
var expanded = Algebraic.Expand(expr);
var xsym = Expr.Symbol("x");
var ysym = Expr.Symbol("y");
var syms = new HashSet<Expr>() {xsym, ysym};
if (Polynomial.IsMultivariatePolynomial(syms, expanded))
{
    var degreeXExpr = Polynomial.Degree(xsym, expanded);
    var degreeX = Evaluate.Evaluate(null, degreeXExpr).RealValue;
    var degreeYExpr = Polynomial.Degree(ysym, expanded);
    var degreeY = Evaluate.Evaluate(null, degreeYExpr).RealValue;
    Console.WriteLine($"Degree X: {degreeX}, Y: {degreeY}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a polynomial in (x, y)");
}
```

Comment: А это на C#? или F#?

Comment: @Grundy: C#, а что?

Comment: А можно что-то подобное провернуть с двумя переменными, т.е выразить x через у?

Comment: @Philippe: Да легко. Обновил ответ.

Comment: @VladD Отлично, спасибо!

Comment: @Philippe: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!